# Android - Different apk for each resolution to reduce size of apk

Tags: android, screens

Is it a good idea to use different APK for different resolutions? I want to reduce the apk file size.

Answer (score 2):

That's a pretty bad idea. Android phones come in lots of different resolutions, and it's impractical to (a) create a different one for each resolution and (b) expect the users to download the right one.

It may or may not be worth it, depending on what you have bundled with the app, to have a tablet version, but probably not.

It'd be much better to just try to follow the [Developer Guide's advice](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) in creating resources appropriate for a wide variety of screens.

Answer (score 1):

I think the question has more value than the answers provided. I am in a similar situation. I think this will be solved by the multiple apk feature soon to be added to the market (june they say)

My app for most devices (non-tablet) is 2.5mb which is nice, with support for the larger tablets its 6.2mb. This is more than double, which is a result of needing exact dimension pngs. I dont want my non tablet users to have to wait for the larger tablet pngs. It just doesn't seem right. I considered multiple apks, but will wait to see what the Android team releases in June. but for now I might just do the larger 6.2mb apk (which im not sure is large in the app world, but its bigger than id like)

Answer (score 0):

Best way is to provide drawables/layout for different resolutions rather than creating different apk depending upon resolutions. Universal application for all resolutions is best than different app for different resolutions.

[Read this for better understanding.](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens-distribution.html)

Apart from this universal application can be ported for devices and tablet.. and only difference in these two are just screen size, as there is no concept of device/tablet for android

Answer (score 0):

First of all I want to know which type of files increase the size of your APK? It is not recommendable to have different apk of the same application for different resolution. If decreasing size of APK is your concern then you can do the following things:

1) Graphics or drawable folder increases apk size. If you have three types of drawable folder for three diff resolution. you can have only one drawable folder and use [9-patch](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/draw9patch.html) graphics to support different screen resolutions which will decrease your apk size

2) Clean up your code in eclipse, optimize your code to get better performance

Comment: Beware of using using 9patches with rounded corners for multiple dimens, as corners will be different and you will have totally different look from ldpi to xhdpi. Sometimes it's easier to use shapes instead of 9patches.